# re-graph: CORS error with remote graphql server

Tags: graphql, clojurescript, re-frame

I'm using re-graph to make a graphql query to a remote server:

```
(re-frame/dispatch [::re-graph/init
                    {:http-url "https://api.spacex.land/graphql"
                     :ws-url nil
                      :http-parameters
                               {:headers {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Content-Type"
                                          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"}}}])
```

But I keep getting this CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3449' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
(re-frame/dispatch [::re-graph/init
                    {:http-url "https://api.spacex.land/graphql"
                     :ws-url nil
                      :http-parameters {:with-credentials? false}}])
```

Comment: does ":http-parameters" actually work? it doesn't seem to have that option.

Answer (score 1):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers are supposed to be set by the Server not the Client. Removing them might be enough to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
(re-frame/dispatch [::re-graph/init 
                      {:ws nil
                       :http {:url "http://api.example.com/graphql"                              
                              :impl {:oauth-token token
                                     :with-credentials? false }}}])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).